# Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException error PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, twilio, twilio-php

I been trying to seen SMS messages from Twilio but get the error message.
I have added a path to a new `curl.cainfo` in the php.info

```
curl.cainfo = c:\wamp\certs\cacert.pem
```

yet I still was getting an error.

ERROR MESSAGE WAS:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain' in C:MYPATH\twilio-php-master\twilio-php-master\Services\Twilio\TinyHttp.php on line 119
```

This is the PHP code:

```
 <?php
 // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
  require ('C:/wamp/www/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library



  $sid = "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9"; 
  $token = "8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2";

$http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
'https://api.twilio.com',
array('curlopts' => array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
)));

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);


 $sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create("+1480xxxxx",   "+1520xxxxx",   "HELP please?! I love you <3", array());
echo $sms->sid;
?>
```

Im using Windows 8, and the the curl version:`cURL Information  7.36.0` is enabled

should I update the curl stated in `https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst`
What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: `WHAT AM I DOING WRONG` - No need to shout, after all it's only a TinyException :)

Comment: sorry i forget that CAPS is shout. haha

Comment: thank you, was missing one. Now back to the  'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'SSL certificate problem:  Do you no how to update the CACERT.pem in WAMP to accept the api.twilio website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Customer Support here!

Did you update cURL as mentioned earlier?

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions

It *should* resolve the issue, if not ping help@twilio.com an email and we can look into it.

Comment: Downloaded curl 7.40 and moved it the the same location as the old cURL but phpinfo will not update from the 7.36. Deleted the 7.36 and the .dll file. how should i update it?

Comment: 404 :( . This is why extra quotation is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make same changes in php.ini inside apache bin folder.
"curl.cainfo = c:\wamp\certs\cacert.pem"
Restart the service.